# Not able to import VotingRegression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter, decision-tree

I am not able to import VotingRegressor from  sklearn in my jupyter.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import VotingRegressor
```

environment:

```
(base) C:\Users\XXX>conda list | grep -i sci
scikit-image              0.14.1                   pypi_0    pypi
scikit-learn              0.20.1                   pypi_0    pypi
scipy                     1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi

conda 4.6.14
```

Restarted the jupyter kernel

```
from sklearn.ensemble import VotingRegressor
```

when i try to import , it throws the error  :

> ImportError: cannot import name 'VotingRegressor' from
>   'sklearn.ensemble'
>   (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble__init__.py)

Answer (score 1):

[`VotingRegressor`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.VotingRegressor.html) was added in version `0.21`, you can check in the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.VotingRegressor.html).

You just need to upgrade you sklearn version.